# TypeScript: How to properly narrow a Union of Intersection Types

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I am currently building a component that accepts some routes, and makes a stepper with a nested router view.

I'm having some trouble with satisfying TypeScript.

I am using `vue-router`'s `RouteLocationRaw` type.

`RouteLocationRaw` is a union of `string` and two intersection types defined as

```
export declare type RouteLocationRaw = string | (RouteQueryAndHash & LocationAsPath & RouteLocationOptions) | (RouteQueryAndHash & LocationAsRelativeRaw & RouteLocationOptions);

export declare interface RouteQueryAndHash {
    query?: LocationQueryRaw;
    hash?: string;
}

export declare interface LocationAsPath {
    path: string;
}

export declare interface RouteLocationOptions {
    replace?: boolean;
    force?: boolean;
    state?: HistoryState;
}

export declare interface LocationAsRelativeRaw {
    name?: RouteRecordName;
    params?: RouteParamsRaw;
}
```

What I would like to do is compare the name of the current route against those passed into the component like so

```
const activeRoute = computed(() => props.routes.find((propRoute) => propRoute.name === route.name))
```

This logic works as I would like, but TypeScript complains. With the approach above I get the following errors.

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'RouteLocationRaw'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

TypeScript seems to automatically assume that the type is a string which is the first part of the union. Already kind of a strange thing to assume, but narrowing beyond a string isn't helpful either.

If I add a case for handling routes that are of `type` `string` TypeScript still doesn't recognize that `name` could be a property of `route`.

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type '(RouteQueryAndHash & LocationAsPath & RouteLocationOptions) | (RouteQueryAndHash & LocationAsRelativeRaw & RouteLocationOptions)'.
  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'RouteQueryAndHash & LocationAsPath & RouteLocationOptions'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to simplify your code to this, which has the same error.

```
declare const propRoute: RouteLocationRaw // the current route, lets say

if (propRoute.name === 'foo') {
  console.log('foo is active')
}
```

---

Now to access a property of any value, that type must declare that property. And when you access a property of a union, then *all* members of that union must declare that. So typescript is not assuming that the value is `string`, it's telling you that it *might* be a `string` and if it is, then this property access doesn't make any sense.

So, to access the `name` property, you need to narrow the union to types that *only* support the `name` property. So you have to filter out `string` and you have to filter out an object property that lacks that property.

That might look like this:

```
if (
  typeof propRoute !== 'string' && // filter out string.
  'name' in propRoute && // require the `name` property.
  propRoute.name === 'foo' // check the name proeprty.
) {
  console.log('foo is active')
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCmA8AcHsCcBcAEATUBjANgQ1qR8BPSPAJWgFd5QAZaNLeAS2gDsSsB3RAXkQGd4sRiwDmiAD6IAFGUqgAiuVCwCAQRbIAElj4ALRADJEtek1aq+ABQb6jsqiYbMWAeUhmWfAJQTp9hUoq6lo6tsZ0TuZ8JKDYTABuoOxcdhQOER5uHt4A3CAQMAgo6Ni4iMJUsABmWGikaQHKahraeogA3sCI3YgAjoEEAPwAXIjkLADWLNAcLF09uqEj-ILCInkAvvlQcEiomDh4Fco1deGmzhbW8PqdPYiQNqMCQqKb24V7JYflLJWn9Tkjky7mcfA6826uEg2DqywARtBoBhQFgWHl7lU4HDRojkaj0ZCVgxQMtxlMZoStmAdkV9qUjn8TrU8MDLtFYk5EskIfcWFgALak0bk6azDE9R6wQV8MmTMVUkD0n5oVgCB6waCQfyjfxs1g8gD0hvwujwaHIsFwf0QmrkABpECj4OC+FgCCBGFVpPNCMRoN7IJrtQ1EABCbi8ADkLzWUcMRmNiCqjAwlUQaRWrxEADp5lH+UL48INVr-AnEEncP1GGUbngAAaF0AN0vEBAEPPdINlho55s8SOIKNY6DxpNoM1oCamvADnugIOEPM+O6IVWefE5jDQERSEdI8rg2oJUBRrzALZAA)